# Is it worth normalizing?

Tags: mysql, database, normalization

I am studying about databases and I have encountered this question.If I have for example the table product_supply which containts Invoice_Id(pk),Product_Id(pk),Date_Of_Supply,Quantity and Value_Of_Product.

```
   | Invoice_ID | Product_ID | Date_Of_Supply | Quantity | Value_Of_Product |
   -------------------------------------------------------------------------
   | AA111111111|      5001  | 08-07-2013     |     50   |       200$       |
   | AA111111111|      5002  | 08-07-2013     |     20   |       300$       |
   | BB222222222|      5003  | 10-09-2013     |     70   |        50$       |
   | CC333333333|      5004  | 15-10-2013     |     100  |        40$       |
   | CC333333333|      5005  | 15-10-2013     |     70   |        25$       |
   | CC333333333|      5006  | 15-10-2013     |     100  |        30$       |
```

As we Can see The table is already in the 1NF form.My question here is.In terms of normalization if it is wise to normalize this table to a 2NF form and have another table for example supply_date with Invoice_ID(pk) and Date_Of_Supply or if having the upper table is ok?

```
    | Invoice_ID | Date_Of_Supply |
    -------------------------------
    |AA111111111 |   08-07-2013   |
    |BB222222222 |   10-09-2013   |
    |CC333333333 |   15-10-2013   |
```

Answer (score 2):

It's definitely worth normalizing. If you need to modify a supply date, with 1NF, you need to update several records; with 2NF, you only need to update one record. Also, note the redundancy of data in 1NF, where the supply date is stored multiple times for each invoice id. Not only does it waste space, it makes it harder to process a query like "list all invoices that were supplied between dates X and Y".

EDIT

As Robert Harvey points out in his comments (which it took me a while to understand because I was being thick for some reason), if you already have a table that has a single row for each `Invoice_ID` (say, an "invoice table"), then you should probably add a column for `Date_Of_Supply` to that table rather than create a new table.

Comment: I understand your logic, but it seems to me that you could just stuff the Date of Supply into the Invoices table, unless there's more than one Date of Supply per invoice.  You seem very sure about your answer, but you haven't asked the OP any questions, and the usage doesn't seem at all apparent from the limited information provided in the question.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - The posted data shows multiple rows with the same date for each invoice ID. If the second normal form yields the table OP describes, then it must be that there is one date per invoice ID.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - I'm confused. Why is a second table not needed for 2NF?

Comment: Presumably the Invoice_Header table already exists.  Primary Key is Invoice_ID.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - OP has table `product_supply`. The question was whether it's worth creating the table `supply_date` in order to have a place to put the supply date in 2NF. I don't see mention of an invoice table.

Comment: And the answer is, no, it's not worth creating another table, if you already have an Invoice table corresponding to a PK of Invoice_ID, and the Invoices have a one to one correspondence with the Supply Date.  Since Invoice_ID already exists (and you're already making some assumptions about the data), I made some assumptions of my own.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - Got it. I was being slow. Updated my answer.

Comment: Im little lost.Can you explain why I dont need a 2nd table please?(too many hours without sleep :(    )

Comment: @Izanagi - You need to remove the `Date_Of_Supply` from the first table for 2NF. The point Robert was making was that you may not need  a _new_ table. He was suggesting that it is quite possible that you already have a table to which you could just add a `Date_Of_Supply` column without violating 2NF.

Comment: @TedHopp so if I want a 2nd table I would have to erase the Date_Of_Supply for the 1st one.Also if I want to keep only the 1st table and not create another one, it would be already in 2NF because the combination of the row Invoice_ID(pk),Product_ID(pk),Date_Of_Supply is only appearing one time,Am I right?

Comment: @Izanagi - The first table is not in 2NF because `Date_Of_Supply` depends on a proper subset of the key (the `Invoice_ID` value only). To achieve 2NF, you need to erase `Date_Of_Supply` from the first table and put those values elsewhere, whether in a new table (as in your question) or in an existing table that has `Invoice_ID` as its entire key (and that has a row for every `Invoice_ID` value in use).

Comment: @TedHopp So as you said in your first answer(without the edit) its worth creating a 2nd table if I want the tables to be in  2NF by extracting the Date_Of_Supply column from the 1st one and adding it to the 2nd one.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the table to second normal form involves removing redundancies in the first normal form table.  The first question is to determine whether there are even any redundancies.

If a redundancy exists, then we should be able to create a second table which does NOT involve the primary key (Invoice_ID) of the first one.  Based on the non PK columns in the first table (namely Product_ID, Date_Of_Supply, Quantity, and Value_Of_Product), it is not clear that any of these are dependent on each other.

As a general rule of thumb, if you have a table where all non PK columns are dependent solely on the PK column of that table, it is already in 2NF.

Comment: What does this mean without the geek-ese?  That he can just put the Date of Supply in his Invoice Header record (assuming one exists)?

Comment: @RobertHarvey _Work has been proceeding in order to bring perfection to the crudely conceived idea of a machine that would not only supply inverse reactive current for use in unilateral phase detractors, but would also be capable of automatically synchronizing cardinal grammeters. Such a machine is the "Turbo-Encabulator..."_

Comment: @MattBall: Awesome.  I understand perfectly.  Now excuse me while I put my tinfoil hat away...  Holy crap, there's actually a [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turboencabulator) about it.

Comment: Yup.  Based on my understanding of the data, that is.  If there were some relationship between the Date of Supply and another column, then this may not be the case.

Comment: _"if you have a table where all non PK columns are dependent solely on the PK column of that table, it is already in 2NF"_ - this is wrong when a table has compound keys. A table is in 2NF if it is in 1NF and furthermore any non-key value is dependent on the _entire_ key, and not on a proper subset of it. In OP's example, the second criterion fails, even though it satisfies your criterion.